# using getline gives error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::istream&, const string&)’

Tags: c++, getline

I'm working on this code and it works with `cin>>partname;` instead of using `getline(cin, partname);` in the showpart function but for only names without blank space. But with using `getline(cin, partname);` it produces an error
`error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::istream&, const string&)’`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

class Inventory
{
  private:
    int partno;
    string partname;
    float cost;
    void getpart()
    {
      cout<<"Enter the part number"<<endl;
      cin>>partno;
      cout<<"Enter the part name"<<endl;
      cin>>partname;
      cout<<"Enter the cost"<<endl;
      cin>>cost;
    }

  public:
    Inventory()
    {
      partno = 0;
      partname = " ";
      cost = 0.0;
    }

    Inventory(int pn,string pname,float c)
    {
      partno = pn;
      partname = pname;
      cost = c;
    }

    void setpart()
    {
      getpart();
    }

    void showpart() const
    {
      cout<<"Inventory details"<<endl;
      cout<<"Part Number: "<<partno<<endl;
      cout<<"Part Name: ";
      getline(cin, partname);
      cout<<"\nCost: "<<cost<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
  Inventory I1(1,"Resistor", 25.0), I2;
  I2.setpart();
  I1.showpart();
  I2.showpart();
}
```

I've looked through similar errors but they seem not to be helpful.Thank you for looking through this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#include <string>` instead of `<cstring>`.

Also:
`void showpart() const` can't be `const` since you update `partname` (which is an odd activity for a function called `show`-something).

I suspect that you want to *show* the `partname`, not to *update* it:

```
void showpart() const
{
  cout<<"Inventory details"<<endl;
  cout<<"Part Number: "<<partno<<endl;
  cout<<"Part Name: "<<partname<<endl;
  cout<<"Cost: "<<cost<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe just to clarify: `showpart()` *should* be `const` - the error is in the implementation of the method.

Comment: @MikaelH Yes, I agree. I suspect a copy/paste error although the `getpart()` function currently uses `cin >> partname`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it. I meant to edit out from getpart() but did it on showpart(). Now it works as intended. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @BreadGenie You're welcome and you didn't waste my time. Your question was clear and self-contained (we could all reproduce the problem) so you made it very easy for people to help _without_ wastning time.